# How to run parallel Elbow method to find appropriate k-clusters

Tags: r, parallel-processing, k-means

The "data.clustering" data frame with size: 943x2

```
> head(data.clustering)
  age gender
2   2      1
3   6      2
4   2      1
5   2      1
6   6      2
7   6      1
```

When I found k values using Elbow method:

```
elbow.k <- function(mydata){
  ## determine a "good" k using elbow
  dist.obj <- dist(mydata);
  hclust.obj <- hclust(dist.obj);
  css.obj <- css.hclust(dist.obj,hclust.obj);
  elbow.obj <- elbow.batch(css.obj);
  #   print(elbow.obj)
  k <- elbow.obj$k
  return(k)
}

# find k value
start.time <- Sys.time();
k.clusters <- elbow.k(data.clustering);
end.time <- Sys.time();
cat('Time to find k using Elbow method is',(end.time - start.time),'seconds with k value:', k.clusters);

The time is so large: 
Time to find k using Elbow method is 24.01472 seconds with k value: 10
```

Can anyone help me to use parallel in r to reduce the time of Elbow method ? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use library(parallel) package in R. But you must consider to import variable and package to your enviroment by using clusterEvalQ(), clusterExport(). 
I think your code will be as below:
library(parallel)

### #

```
elbow.k <- function(mydata){
  ## determine a "good" k using elbow
  dist.obj <- dist(mydata);
  hclust.obj <- hclust(dist.obj);
  css.obj <- css.hclust(dist.obj,hclust.obj);
  elbow.obj <- elbow.batch(css.obj);
  #   print(elbow.obj)
  k <- elbow.obj$k
  return(k)
}

# find k value
no_cores <- detectCores();
cl<-makeCluster(no_cores);
clusterEvalQ(cl, library(GMD));
clusterExport(cl, list("clustering.kmeans")); // add variables and functions to your enviroment
start.time <- Sys.time();
k.clusters <- parSapply(cl, 1, function(x) elbow.k(data.clustering)); // or parLapply - it returns list. 
end.time <- Sys.time();
cat('Time to find k using Elbow method is',(end.time - start.time),'seconds with k value:', k.clusters);
stopCluster(cl);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a shared-memory parallelism example that creates the elbow plot using k-means.

```
library(parallel)

elbow <- function(min_max, frame) {
  set.seed(42)
  wss <- (nrow(frame)-1)*sum(apply(frame,2,var))
  for (i in min_max) {
    wss[i] <- sum(kmeans(frame,centers=i,algorithm = c('MacQueen'))$withinss)
  }
  return(wss)
}

parallel_elbow <- function(kmax, frame_choice) {
  # create separate kmin:kmax vectors 
  cut_point <- 3
  centers_vec <- 2:kmax    
  x <- seq_along(centers_vec)
  chunks <- split(centers_vec, ceiling(x/cut_point))

  # use shared-memory parallelism on function of choice
  results <- mclapply(chunks, FUN=elbow, frame=frame_choice)

  # gather the results of each parallel run 
  no_nas <- list()
  for(i in 1:length(results)) { 
    no_nas[i] <- list(as.numeric(na.omit(results[[i]])))
  }

  vec <- unlist(no_nas)
  final_vec <- setdiff(vec, vec[1])
  final_vec <- append(vec[1],final_vec)

  # create scree plot of all wss values
  plot(1:length(final_vec), final_vec, type="b", xlab="Number of Clusters", ylab="Within groups sum of squares", pch = 16, main="Elbow Plot", col="steelblue")
}
```

Use like this:

```
parallel_elbow(100, iris[,-5])
```

[image]

Comparing runtimes on a document term matrix with 2176 documents:

```
system.time(elbow(1:10, dtm))
user  system elapsed 
83.130   1.450  84.843 

system.time(parallel_elbow(10, dtm))
user  system elapsed 
21.097   0.653  48.132
```

Normal in orange, parallel in blue.

[image]

Comment: nice answer, can you provide some comments on the elbow method to have a better understanding of the entire approach.